# How to log out one user while the other user remain log in using the same Browser at same time..?

Tags: php

1. Hi I am newer to Php I need your help...! Two user log in to a site
   using same browser from one PC. When I want to log out one user the
   other automatically log out (unset the session of one user the
   session of 2nd one also unset). Is there any way to log out one user
   and the other one remain log in in the site using same Browser.
   coding 1:create_account.php       Registration Form  
   User Name       Father's
   Name       Password
        
   Confirm Password 

    
     
          2:login.php
   0) { session_start();
   $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
   $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id']; header('location:home.php'); }
   else { $msg = "Invalid User Name Or password !"; } } ?>    Admin Pannel   User
   Name     Password          3:

   ## Welcome

   4:signout.php  Sign Out

---

Comment: first of all this is a security concern if more than 1 person is able to login to your website using same browser and same pC.

Comment: what you're doing is a bit unorthodox, you'll need to show how you are setting the session when a user logs in

Comment: @Mrcoder He is trying to implement Gmail kind of stuff where two users can login at same time. But Logout is not possible for anyone.

Comment: @user2936213 in gmail also more than 1 person cannnot login using same browser in the same PC,u have to use different browser.

Comment: Gmail's dual login is something vastly different and implemented in quite a complex way I would expect. The real question here is WHY do you want this feature? Is there any real need for it or somebody just finds it "cool" without realizing the risks behind such thing? Also users wouldn't expect it and it would be very confusing if not well explained IMHO.

Comment: @Mrcoder Gmail is having this functionality in which you have to click on `add an account` and you can open another gmail account.

Comment: @Veseliq yes somebody just finds it "cool" without realizing the risks behind such thing.

Comment: @user2936213 i am already aware of that but in that also now two user can login at the same time with the same browser on same pc.

Comment: I think, this might beee possible...although very high security risks. If, we maintain the session on server, for example db and pass the session id as url parameter, i guess this can be done, coz every request and response to the server would accompany the respective session Ids. Whenevr a user logs out, we have to delete/unflag that session on db or server.Technically, since PHP doesnt not use L5 layer of OSI, this can be possible. Expert comments solicited....

Comment: irctc.co.in uses this techinique. Although they use both cookie as well as url parameter for additional security, but notice that if you change the session id on url, you will be forcefully logged out, since the system wont recognize you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is `No`. You will have trouble maintaining 2 different sessions for 2 users under same browser, there will be huge security risks, so there is a reason none of the big websites you see would allow this.

Comment: doing +1 as i think this is the short and the better answer to this question.